# Exibir modal ao enviar dados para o banco com PHP

Tags: php, modal

Estou tentando fazer com que, após o usuário clique no botão de enviar, o sistema exiba um modal com alguns dados. Porém não estou conseguindo por que mesmo sem preencher nada no formulário, ao clicar no botão, o modal é exibido:

**FORMULÁRIO**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row cadastro">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" id="nome" style="color:black;border-color:black" placeholder="Digite seu nome" required="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>E-mail:</label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" style="color:black;border-color:black" placeholder="Digite seu email" required="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <label>genero:</label>
      <select class="select" name="genero" id="genero">
            <option disabled="" selected="" value="Outro">Selecione uma opção</option>
            <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
            <option value="Feminino">Feminino</option>
            <option value="Outro">Outro</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <label>localidade</label>
      <select class="select" name="localidade" id="localidade">
            <option value="Não informado" disabled="" selected="">Selecione uma opção</option>
            <option value="Centro">Centro</option>
            <option value="Banguê">Banguê</option>
            <option value="Tucum">Tucum</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <label>idade:</label>
      <input type="number" name="idade" class="form-control" style="color:black;border-color:black" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48" min="1" max="120" name="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-common" name="cadDados" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Enviar Dados</button>
</form>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CÓDIGO PHP**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['cadDados'])) {

        $nome = trim(strip_tags($_POST['nome']));
        $email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
        $genero = trim(strip_tags($_POST['genero']));
        $localidade = trim(strip_tags($_POST['localidade']));
        $doenca = trim(strip_tags($_POST['doenca']));
        $idade = trim(strip_tags($_POST['idade']));
        $insert = "INSERT INTO tb_grafico (nome,email,genero,localidade,tipo_doenca,idade) VALUES (:nome,:email,:genero,:localidade,:doenca,:idade)";

        try{
            //Proteção contra SQLINJECT
            $result = $con->prepare($insert);
            $result->bindParam(':nome',$nome,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':genero',$genero,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $result->bindParam(':localidade',$localidade,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':doenca',$doenca,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':idade',$idade,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->execute();
            $contar = $result->rowCount();
            if ($contar>0) {
                echo "<div class ='alert alert-sucess' role='alert'><strong>Cadastrado com sucesso!</strong></div>";
            }
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "<strong>Erro de sql: </strong>".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ao invés de usar o evento direto no botão, vc pode tentar um javascript que abra o modal sob as condições que você determinar... Exemplo: $('.botao').click(funciona(){ If(condição) $('modal').modal('open'}); substituindo os valores botão e modal pela classe ou id dos mesmos.

Answer (score 1):

Então, já passei por isto e parece que a sua solução é o AJAX com validação HTML5. A sua pergunta não ficou bem clara, mas encaro como um sim. Primeiro, você altera o seu botão para não lançar o modal:

```
<button class="btn btn-common" name="cadDados" type="submit">Enviar Dados</button>
```

Agora, os campos que você quer que sejam validados você adiciona um required:

```
<select class="select" name="genero" id="genero" required>
```

Atenção: nunca deve-se fazer a validação apenas no frontend, faça também no backend.

Adicione um id no seu formulário (neste caso, "my_form"):

```
<form role="form" action="" id="my_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Aí você utiliza um Jquery para detectar se deram submit no seu formulário (detalhe: se um campo required não for preenchido, o usuário recebe um alerta na hora):

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();//Impede envio
    event.stopPropagation();//Impede envio

    //Pega as informações do formulário
    var frm = $("#my_form");
    var data = {};
    $.each(this, function(i, v){
        var input = $(v);
        data[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
        delete data["undefined"];
    });
    $.ajax({
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type:frm.attr("method"),
        url:frm.attr("action"),
        dataType:'json',
        data:JSON.stringify(data),
        success:function(data) {
            //Aqui você pode fazer um código para saber se deu tudo certo ou ocorreu um erro no backend
            $('#MEU_MODAL').modal('show');//Mostra o modal
        }
    });
}
```

Eu sei que a resposta foi longa, o código não foi testado, mas já é um caminho a ser seguido. Pesquise também no google: Jquery PHP Ajax e você terá vários exemplos dos mais fáceis aos mais completos.

**Fazendo sem ajax:**

Primeiro, você altera o seu botão para não lançar o modal:

```
<button class="btn btn-common" name="cadDados" type="submit">Enviar Dados</button>
```

Agora, os campos que você quer que sejam validados você adiciona um required:

```
<select class="select" name="genero" id="genero" required>
```

Ok, com isto o formulário só envia se preencherem algo. Mas claro que no PHP você também deve validar isto ok amigo? Agora, nós vamos pegar o código PHP e colocar na mesma página do formulário, coloque este código:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['cadDados'])) {

        $nome = trim(strip_tags($_POST['nome']));
        $email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
        $genero = trim(strip_tags($_POST['genero']));
        $localidade = trim(strip_tags($_POST['localidade']));
        $doenca = trim(strip_tags($_POST['doenca']));
        $idade = trim(strip_tags($_POST['idade']));
        $insert = "INSERT INTO tb_grafico (nome,email,genero,localidade,tipo_doenca,idade) VALUES (:nome,:email,:genero,:localidade,:doenca,:idade)";

        try{
            //Proteção contra SQLINJECT
            $result = $con->prepare($insert);
            $result->bindParam(':nome',$nome,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':genero',$genero,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $result->bindParam(':localidade',$localidade,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':doenca',$doenca,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':idade',$idade,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->execute();
            $contar = $result->rowCount();
            if ($contar>0) {
                $('#MEU_MODAL_SUCESSO').modal('show');
            }
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            $('#MEU_MODAL_DE_ERRO').modal('show');
        }
    }
?>
```

Eu fiz de uma forma meio grosseira, um modal para sucesso e outro modal para erro. O que vai acontecer é que a página vai recarregar e caso haja erro, vai disparar o modal de erro, caso contrário o de sucesso.

Estes códigos precisam ser aprimorados, mas aí é com você. Boa sorte!

Comment: Não funcionou :/ não exibe mais nada no site quando coloco o codigo sem ajax... e com ajax não funcionou, continuou o mesmo erro

Comment: Edite a resposta colocando o código que você utilizou e o exato erro.